# Stirring bar cleaning

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I have a small question concerning the stirring bars cleaning. I use mine in BOD test wastewater for 5 days and I want to clean them so my question is can I soak them overnight with sodium hypochlorite (Javel) or it can affect their magnetic ability or something?

Comment: The magnetic properties of a stirring bar are not affected by any chemical treatment like cleaning with hypochlorite.

Comment: I found sodium in liquid ammonia got them really clean!

Comment: @Maurice Erm … this lab had a stirring bar lose its magnetic property. I suspect the outer teflon or whatever layer died a slow and painful death and then something acidic affected the metal core. So true in principle but exceptions exist ;)

Comment: No. No chemical treatment can change the magnetic state of an iron piece. The only thing that could change the magnetization of an iron bar is the heat (above the Curie point) and the time.

Comment: Is this really a question from someone doing chemistry?

Comment: Alchimista thanks for your kind reply I was asking because it's the first time I soak them in Javel for 24 hours, anyway learn from the above how to reply to people question gently ;)

Comment: @Maurice I believe that you mean no chemistry happening around a magnet can change its magnetic properties. Obviously isn't the case if the magnet react itself.

Comment: @ShafikSaad sorry. I apologise if it turns impolite. Nothing was aimed at you. Rather the question would have been not great but more sounding if formulated as "can a prolonged treatment in eau de Javel modify the Teflon coating of a stirring bar?". I thought to delete it but then a reader could think of a more personal impolite attack, and that was no in my scope. So I let it there. Mods might consider removal(s) for the cleanness of the page.

Comment: Alchimista your apology means so much thank you for your kidness and yes that was my question usually I soak my bars when I arrive to work and take them out before leaving but I forgot last time and I was affraid if the coating will be damaged... Thank you again for your apology and wish you the best :)